# How do I make dynamic SQL to insert 'date' variable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure created in SQL Server 2014 as

```
create procedure ProcAddDate
    @tableName varchar(10),
    @inpDate date
as
    declare @sqlInsString varchar(max)

    set @sqlInsString = 'insert into '+ @tableName + ' values('
    set @sqlInsString = @sqlInsString + @inpDate + ')'

    execute(@sqlInsString)
go
```

However, when I attempt to execute this statement, SQL Server throws up an error

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ProcAddDate, Line 7
>   The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

How do I create a stored procedure which would let me add a date to a table, by taking in a value of type 'date' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you *have* to do this (it's usually a sign of a broken data model if you're parametrizing table names), use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) so that you can pass the data across, unmolested, with the correct type (rather than forcing it into and then back out of a string):

```
create procedure ProcAddDate
@tableName sysname,
@inpDate date
as
    declare @sqlInsString nvarchar(max);
    set @sqlInsString = N'insert into '+ @tableName + ' values(@inpDate)';
    declare @parms nvarchar(max);
    set @parms = N'@inpDate date';
    execute sp_executesql @sqlInsString,@parms,@inpDate;
go
```

(I've also made a few other stylistic changes to the above)

Comment: '...broken data model...', '...parameterizing table names...'
I'd be glad if you could explain this.

Comment: @cybernomad1993 - you have multiple tables which (apparently) have the same structure and are dealt with in the same manner. When this happens, what's normally happened is that part of your *data* has become embedded in the table names. E.g. an organization shouldn't normally have `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables. They should have an `Employees` table and an additional column for gender.  In ~95% of cases where I see people parametrizing tables, this is what's happened.

Comment: adding to @Damien_The_Unbeliever comments, another scenario is tables 'by period': Sales_2015Q1, Sales_2015Q2. there should exist the table 'Sales' with a 'Date/Quarter/YouGetIt' column that allows to achieve the very same results with more flexibility and lower maintenance effort. 'but the table will grow huge!': so what? that's what a rdbms is for, handle huge amount of data...

Comment: But, what if my intention is to make a file upload/encryption program, implemented as a web app, where a table in a database would hold details about files uploaded by a user (with the files themselves being stored in a file system)?

Comment: a `file` table with at least 2 columns: `userid`, `NameOfTheFileOnFilesystem`. but this is a question better asked on dba, i think

Comment: Great trick, have been banging my head over date/time conversion.